# How center the video on narrow displays

Tags: html, css, video, screen

I have a [html page](https://tatrytec.eu/) which contains video as background. The problem is on the narrow screen where the content is out of the screen because it is aligned to right. How can I center the video content in video html tag?

Wide screen
[image]
Narrow screen
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to you .video CSS

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

so it becomes

```
#wrapper, video {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get the bounties?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code totaly, there was a little problem also in CSS, wrong pronunciation *width* & *height*.
This is the result : (read the last line of the css code)(and put other codes in your file I deleted them)

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #d0d0ff;
    color: #ffa68d
}

#wrapper,
video {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap
}

#wrapper #content {
    padding: 75px;
    font-size: 40px;
    max-width: 550px
}

#wrapper #content h1 {
    margin-top: 0
}

#wrapper #side {
    padding: 75px;
    font-size: 25px
}

#wrapper #side ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 14px
}

#wrapper #side ul li a {
    color: #ffa68d;
    text-decoration: none
}

#wrapper #side ul li a:active,
#wrapper #side ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffd8ce;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #ffc7b7
}

#wrapper .translateInit {
    transform: translateY(-450px);
    opacity: 0
}

#wrapper .translateInit-2 {
    transform: translate(450px);
    opacity: 0
}

#wrapper .translateInit-3 {
    transform: translateY(450px);
    opacity: 0
}

#wrapper .translateInit-4 {
    transform: translate(-450px);
    opacity: 0
}

#wrapper .translate {
    transition: all .25s
}

.fs-40 {
    font-size: 40px
}

.fs-30 {
    font-size: 30px
}

.about-hover:hover {
    color: #ffd8ce
}

@media (max-width:1020px) {
    #wrapper {
        flex-direction: column
    }

    #wrapper #content {
        font-size: 25px !important;
        padding: 25px;
        text-align: center
    }

    #wrapper #side {
        padding: 25px
    }

    #wrapper #side ul li {
        padding: 7px;
        text-align: center
    }

    .fs-30 {
        font-size: 20px
    }
    video {
        top: 0;
        // You can change this perscentage as you want
        right: -60%;
    }
}

// Mobile First
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  video {
    top: 0;
    // You can change this perscentage as you want
    right: -70%
  }
}
```

```html
    <video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" __idm_id__="693906433">
        <source src="https://tatrytec.eu/storage/homepage/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. Here is
            a <a href="https://tatrytec.eu/myVideo.mp4">link to the video</a> instead.</p>
    </video>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="side" class="translate">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://tatrytec.eu/">Vitajte</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://tatrytec.eu/about">O nás</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://tatrytec.eu/contact">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://tatrytec.eu/najnovsie">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="welcome" class="translate">
                <h1>Tatrytec.eu</h1>
                <div>Let your dreams <br>come true...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wait a bit to see the video it seems that the video loads slowly on stackoverflow.

Comment: Where did you found wrong pronunciation of width and height?

Comment: I just downloaded your css file and first of all, my text editor recognized your problem. You can put this code instead it's completely the same.

Comment: I am usind scss preprocessor. I dont see any problem.

Comment: Oh you are right. But it does not cause any issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
.video {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

add this code